# how to read nodes data from json file in visual c+++

Tags: c++, json, nodes

Using below code we are able to access first data from the first node of JSON file but We want to read all values present in below JSON file. please provide your inputs for this issue.

typedef boost::property_tree::ptree TreeNode; TreeNode root; boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json(std::string(igIntObj_XLS.buffer), root); if(root.size()<=0) { LOGMSG<<"JSON_File is Empty.\n"; return bReturn; } namespace pt = boost::property_tree;
i want to  read only ""**Datavalue: 0,7**" from below json file:
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "orderNum": 1,
        "title": "Main socio-economic indicators",
        "subtitle": null,
        "isVisible": true,
        "regionId": 741880,
        "datas": [
            {
                "id": 629147,
                "orderNum": 1,
                "title": "Population",
                "subtitle": "(1.12.2019, thousand person)",
                "dataValue": "18 611,1",
                "icon": "naselenie.png",
                "isVisible": true
            },
            {
                "id": 629148,
                "orderNum": 2,
                "title": "GDP ",
                "subtitle": "(January-September 2019, %)",
                "dataValue": "104,3",
                "icon": "vvp.png",
                "isVisible": true
            },
            {
                "id": 629149,
                "orderNum": 3,
                "title": "Inflation ",
                "subtitle": "(December 2019 per to December 2018, %)",
                "dataValue": "5,4",
                "icon": "inflation.png",
                "isVisible": true
            },
            {
                "id": 629150,
                "orderNum": 4,
                "title": "Inflation ",
                "subtitle": "(December 2019 per to November 2019, %)",
                "dataValue": "0,7",
                "icon": "inflation.png",
                "isVisible": true
            },
            {
                "id": 629151,
                "orderNum": 5,
                "title": "Rate of unemployment",
                "subtitle": "(December 2019, %, estimated data)",
                "dataValue": "4,8",
                "icon": "bezrabotica.png",
                "isVisible": true
            },
c++

Comment: Never heard of `iGLib` and couldn't find it in the first few ages of a google search. Wait, found it for Java, I think.

Comment: Why the fixation on `trim()`? It would be better to use a standard date parser.

Comment: vector <string> date = std::Split(sFidVal,"/", true); 
i am getting" 01" "28" now how can i store only 01 in another variable in c++? –

Comment: There is no function named `std::Split` in the C++ standard library. Where does this come from?

Answer (score 2):

My advice is: don't.

The standard library has tools to do this easily. Old-schoolers would probably just use `sscanf`:

```
char input[] = "27/01/2020";

int day, month, year;

sscanf(input, "%d/%d/%d", &day, &month, &year);
```

If you like streams, you might prefer the `get_time` manipulator:

```
std::stringstream input("27/01/2020");

tm date;

input >> std::gettime(&date, "%d/%m/%Y");
```

...and then `date.tm_mday` will contain `27`, `date.tm_month` will contain `01`, and `date.tm_year` will contain 120 (i.e., the year - 1900).

If you really want (or need) to use `iGlib::Trim`, you'll probably have to consult that library's documentation--it's not one that seems to be well known (which is part of why I'd advise avoiding it).

Comment: vector <string> date = std::Split(sFidVal,"/", true); i am getting" 01" "28" now how can i store only 01 in another variable in c++?

Comment: @ShireenKhan one possibility would be something like `sscanf(input, "%*d/%d/%*d", &month);`

Answer (score 1):

use `split(date, '/')` .

```
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& s, char delimiter)
{
   std::vector<std::string> tokens;
   std::string token;
   std::istringstream tokenStream(s);
   while (std::getline(tokenStream, token, delimiter))
   {
      tokens.push_back(token);
   }
   return tokens;
}
```

Taken from [here](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/04/21/how-to-split-a-string-in-c/)

Comment: using Split function i am getting" 01" "28" now how can i store only 01 in another variable in c++?

Comment: `auto vec = split(date, '/');
std::string month = vec.at(1);`